# Boolean test if an archive is corrupt

Tags: powershell, 7zip

After creating a zip file, I'd like to add a confirmation if it was successful.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$env:ZRoot\7z.exe" -ArgumentList "t D:\MyBackup\Log5.zip *.* -r" -Wait -PassThru
```

I get this as an output:

```
 Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName                                                                                                                                                                                            

 -------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------                                                                                                                                                                                            
  4       2      248       1088     6     0.02  10236 7z
```

How do I capture a boolean test from the command line, if a zip file is corrupt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `Start-Process`. Just run the command and check the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable (i.e., the exit code of the executable). Per the 7-Zip documentation, a non-zero exit code indicates an error. Example (not tested):

```
& $(Join-Path $Env:ZRoot "7z.exe") t "D:\path name\whatever.zip"
if ( $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0 ) { "There was an error" }
```

Comment: & "$env:ZRoot\7z.exe" t "D:\MyBackup\Log5.zip"
If ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0){ Write-Error "Backup is corrupted."}